# Possible to use DotNetBrowser with UWP Applications?

Tags: uwp, dotnetbrowser

I see that DotNetBrowser works with WPF what about UWP Applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to Cordova to use Chrome when running its windows uwp apps

It's not possible currently in Cordova project which target to Windows Platform, you will get this exception

```
Failed to add reference to 'DotNetBrowser.Chromium'
```

If you have a traditional desktop application(like Win32, WPF, and Windows Forms), you might check this tool: [Convert your desktop application to a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root)

> UWP using Desktop Conversion extensions is a bridge that enables you
>   to convert your Windows desktop application (like Win32, Windows
>   Forms, and WPF) or game to a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app or
>   game. For more info, see [Guide to UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx). After conversion, your
>   Windows desktop application is packaged, serviced, and deployed in the
>   form of a UWP app package (an .appx or an .appxbundle) targeting
>   Windows 10 Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

DotNetBrowser is not supported for UWP Apps. you can use WebView control instead.
here is the doc.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx
WebView does not support Chrome Engine or something like that.

Comment: WevView? Do you mean the native WebView? I want to Cordova to use Chrome when running its windows uwp apps.